# android get my app's PackageInfo from jni

Tags: android, c++, java-native-interface

Java code to get package info:

```
/**
 * get PackageInfo
 * @param context
 * @return
 */
public PackageInfo getPackageSign(Context context) {
    PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
    List<PackageInfo> apps = pm.getInstalledPackages(PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
    Iterator<PackageInfo> iter = apps.iterator();
    while (iter.hasNext()) {
        PackageInfo info = iter.next();
        String packageName = info.packageName;
        if (packageName.equals("your package name")) {
            return info;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Is that any way to get my app's package info using c++ in jni?

Comment: Yup. But it will be at least 3x more code.

Comment: What I would suggest doing is writing this function in Java, then calling it from C++ using JNI.